# How to handle after ajaxSubmit()

Tags: django, google-app-engine, jquery-plugins

Previously, my code in the following was working fine and the ajaxSubmit request was done successfully.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#restaurant_photo_upload').submit(function() { 
                var options = { 
                    clearForm: true        // clear all form fields after successful submit
                }; 
                $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);

                return false; 
            });

            $('[name=upload_restaurant_photo_btn]').click(function(){
                alert("Uploading. . . .?");
                $('#restaurant_photo_upload').submit();
            });
```

The code to handler the post:

```
class AddRestaurantPhotoHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
def post(self):
    ......
    ......
    ...... 
    self.render(u'restaurant_profile', restaurant=restaurant, restaurant_key=restaurant_key)
```

Previously, after adding the ajaxSubmit() code instead of normal submit, I was able to get through the process with self.redirect. However, recently, it's throwing me error, "object has no attribute 'render'

If using self.render is the only workaround in this case, how do I pass additional query strings or data back to the template?

I'm confused in a sense that, I thought ajax doesn't need to render the page again.

Comment: I hope you can solve whether it's the python or javascript or both. Some python was posted to admit `blobstoreuploadhandler` return status 200 so if you modify dev_appserver you can or wait for SDK 1.5.4 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-python/vnvhUG1-UN0 you can also look at the exmple called FileHangar that Nick Johnson blogged that uses jquery to submit files with app engine blobstore api http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Implementing-a-dropbox-service-with-the-Blobstore-API-part-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently a BlobstoreUploadHandler requires a redirect so you can pass query strings like this:
`self.redirect("/restaurant_profile/%d/success" % (restaurant.key().id()))`

If then more variables are needed you can save it to the datastore and display it.

I asked in the google groups why we can't make a normal render with blobstoreuploadhandler and the answer is that this requirement is removed already on production and the requirement is said the be removed with dev_appserver starting from SDK 1.5.4.

I've deployed a similar upload with plupload that can upload files with jquery and plugin and my javascript for the upload is

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/plupload/plupload.full.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/plupload/jquery.plupload.queue.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      uploader = $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
        runtimes: 'flash,html5,gears,html4',
                use_query_string: false,
                multipart: true,
                flash_swf_url: '/static/plupload/plupload.flash.swf',
                filters: [],
      }).pluploadQueue();
      uploader.bind('UploadFile', function(up, file) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/generate_upload_url',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
              up.settings.url = data;
            },
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: How about passing object rather than just string?

Besides, is the Ajax behaves accordingly? I still can see the browser seem to refresh the page. I thought Ajax is supposed to refresh only the part that we wanted to perform the request?

Comment: We should be able to pass object rather that just string as soon as SDK 1.5.4 comes. Until then they said it already works in production. The Ajax with jquery I use is called plupload and I pasted it to the answer. If the whole page is refreshed for every upload in a queue then plupload has a different behavior depending on runtime (flash/html5/gears/html4)